# TinyMCE Version 3.X - How to add a Color Highlighter in its toolbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, color-picker

I want to add a Color Highlighter to TinyMCE Toolbar.

Below is my code for ToolBar Options:

```
toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | bold italic |  underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | strikethrough | superscript | subscript |  code | bullist | numlist outdent indent | link  image | fontselect | forecolor | forecolorpicker"
```

Below is my code for Plugins:

```
 plugins: ["paste autolink fullscreen table lists link image charmap print preview anchor code textcolor"],
```

Using the above lines of code, I do see the Font ForeColor Option.

I want to add a "Yellow" Text Highlighter in the toolbar.

Please suggest!

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this property to you init json:

```
textcolor_map:["FFFF00", "Yellow"]
```

hope it help you.